# Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{r}$ (Coulomb potential)

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics, uniform-convergence

When calculating the Fourier transform of a function of the form $f(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \left|\vec{r}\right|}$, one encounters the problem that the resulting integral does not converge, i.e.
$$\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{4 \pi |\vec{r}|}\right]\!\!\left(\vec{p}\right) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{4\pi |\vec{r}|} e^{-i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{r}}\mathrm{d}^3\! r = \frac{1}{\left|\vec{p}\right|} \int_0^\infty \sin\!\left(\left|\vec{p}\right| \cdot r\right) \mathrm{d}r$$
(see e.g. [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1830v1), appendix A). This problem comes up when trying to express the Coulomb potential in momentum space.

In the link above, this is circumvented by introducing an attenuating factor $e^{- \lambda \left|\vec{r}\right|}$ and subsequently taking the limit $\lambda \to 0$, i.e.
$$\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{4 \pi |\vec{r}|}e^{- \lambda \left|\vec{r}\right|}\right]\!\!\left(\vec{p}\right) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{4\pi |\vec{r}|} e^{- \left(\lambda\left|\vec{r}\right| + i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{r}\right)}\mathrm{d}^3\! r = \frac{1}{\left|\vec{p}\right|^2 + \lambda^2}$$
$$\stackrel{\lambda\to 0}{\Rightarrow} \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{4 \pi |\vec{r}|}\right] = \frac{1}{\left|\vec{p}\right|^2}$$

My question is whether this is mathematically justified. Essentially, as I see it, this operation comes down to exchanging the order of taking the limit and the integration:
$$\mathcal{F}\left[\lim_{\lambda\to 0}\frac{1}{4 \pi |\vec{r}|}e^{- \lambda \left|\vec{r}\right|}\right]\!\!\left(\vec{p}\right) \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{\lambda\to 0}\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{4 \pi |\vec{r}|}e^{- \lambda \left|\vec{r}\right|}\right]\!\!\left(\vec{p}\right)$$

I'm guessing the question can somehow be answered with the concept of [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence), but mathematical details like these are not often part of my physics courses, so I'm not very familiar with its application.

Comment: Another idea: $\frac{1}{r}$ is a locally integrable function in $\mathbb{R}^{n}/0$ which can be identified with a tempered distribution. Since $\frac{1}{r}$ is homogeneous of degree $1,$ its transform must be of the form $c \frac{1}{\vert \xi \vert ^{2}}$ (because your function is radial, the FT is rotationally invariant and it takes homogeneous distributrions of degree $k$ to homogeneous distributions of degree $-n-k$, with $n$ the dimension).

Comment: The constant $c$ you can compute using the following two facts:   -The gaussian is an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform   -Plancherel identity

Comment: If we interpret $f(\vec{r})\propto r^{-1}$ as a Coulomb potential, then the attenuated version is known as a [Yukawa potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential). So that would be a word worth searching under.

Comment: This Physics.SE question asks much the same question, though of course the audience in that case is different: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7462.

Comment: @Qwertuy Unfortunately, I don't really know the rigorous mathematical theory behind distributions (yet), so understanding that would be difficult to me.

Comment: @Semiclassical I haven't heard of Yukawa potentials – I'll have to do some reading on that. I hadn't seen the Physics.SE question; if I had, I might not have even posted it here, although I think Math.SE is a better place for it.